# Как сгруппировать свойства своего контрола

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

Имеется код, который создаёт новый контрол на основе стандартной кнопки. Там есть пара новых свойств, одно из которых `CornerRound` - которое отвечает за то, какие углы будут закруглены, однако в обозревателе свойств на вкладках конструкторов оно отображается некорректно.
Пример, как это должно выглядеть (Свойство Margin с несколькими вложенными полями):
[image: Скрин поля Margin из стандартного TextBox]

Пример, как это выглядит сейчас:
[image: Скрин отображаемых свойств]

Как видно, из скрина [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCn4O.png) группа `CornerRound` отображается просто как неизменяемое поле. Помогите это исправить.

Код:

```cs
    public struct CornerRound
    {
        private const bool defVal = true;
        public bool LeftUp { get; set; }
        public bool LeftDown { get; set; }
        public bool RightUp { get; set; }
        public bool RightDown { get; set; }
        private bool? all;
        public bool All { get => all ?? false; set { all = LeftUp = LeftDown = RightUp = RightDown = value; } }

        public CornerRound(bool leftUp = defVal, bool leftDown = defVal, bool rightUp = defVal, bool rightDown = defVal)
        {
            LeftUp = leftUp; LeftDown = leftDown; RightUp = rightUp; RightDown = rightDown;
            all = leftUp & leftDown & rightUp & rightDown;
        }
        public CornerRound(bool all = defVal) : this(all, all, all, all) { }
    }

    public partial class DP_FlatButton : Button
    {
        private int borderSize = 0;
        private int borderRadius = 0;
        private Color borderColor = Color.Black;
        public CornerRound cornerRound = new CornerRound(true);

        [Category("DP Custom UI")]
        public int BorderSize
        {
            get => borderSize;
            set
            {
                borderSize = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Category("DP Custom UI")]
        public int BorderRadius
        {
            get => borderRadius;
            set
            {
                borderRadius = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Category("DP Custom UI")]
        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get => borderColor;
            set
            {
                borderColor = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Category("DP Custom UI")]
        public CornerRound CornerRound { get => this.cornerRound; set => this.cornerRound = value; }
        [Category("DP Custom UI")]
        public Color TextColor { get => base.ForeColor; set => base.ForeColor = value; }
        [Category("DP Custom UI")]
        public Color BackgroundColor { get => base.BackColor; set => base.BackColor = value; }
    }
```

Comment: А что если на структуру `CornerRound` навесить атрибут `[Serializable]`?

Comment: @aepot , Попробовал. Свойство появилось, но только в виде строки, а не выпадающего списка, со статичной записью "tools.ui.CornerRound" (tools.ui - мой неймспейс) (https://imgur.com/1GJB6in)

Comment: Кстати, а что если кто-то захочет скруглить к примеру 2 угла 10, и 2 угла на 20. Как я понял - это невозможно. Но зачем вы накладываете такое ограничение? В WPF например такого ограничения нет.

Comment: Ну, дальше разбирайтесь, что за атрибут такой `[Serializable]`, как работает и зачем нужен. Я без понятия как оно работает, я наугад сказал.

Comment: Думал об этом. Но как сделать общее свойство "All"(как у некоторых стандартных) которое скруглит мне все углы - я тоже пока не знаю(

Comment: Возмите тип [`Padding`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.padding?view=netframework-4.8), не изобретайте велосипед. Или сделайте по образу и подобию, вот исходник - https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms.Primitives/src/System/Windows/Forms/Padding.cs

Comment: Поле должно быть приватным. / [PropertyGrid FAQ](https://rsdn.org/article/dotnet/PropertyGridFAQ.xml) - полезная статья. / [PaddingConverter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Padding.cs,16b76696031d1f40) - смотрите исходники и по аналогии сделайте TypeConverter для своей структуры.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov не стоит рефить код устаревшего фреймворка - [PaddingConverter.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/src/System.Windows.Forms.Primitives/src/System/Windows/Forms/PaddingConverter.cs).